# VSCode extension LICENSE text encoding

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any information about what encoding should I use for LICENSE file for VSCode extension?

I was published plugin with LICENSE file in UTF-8 in russian language, but it shows incorrectly from VSCode.

see https://1c-soft.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/1c-soft/1c-executor-plugin/0.1.0/1592578562713/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.License

UPD: Plugin with LSP support. Published to marketplace.
If I look through web marketplace, it is OK - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/1c-soft.1c-executor-plugin/license

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is it a theme ext, workbench ext or a language server? Are you trying to publish it to the marketplace?

Comment: @tHeSiD updated my question

Comment: Yes, the file is fine, if you save it from the browser and open it. Read more about how http servers handle encoding here https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Comment: @tHeSiD thanks! so I need to rewrite LICENSE file in html? Now it is a plain text.

Comment: If you want it to improve it, i'd suggest using markdown format instead of direct html.

Comment: @tHeSiD thanks. Tried with markdown, but it does not helped. Resolved by saving file with UTF-8 with BOM